# Error in CoreData when trying to save an array. 'Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject''

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using CoreData to save a tableView to the device. I am relatively new to CoreData, and cannot figure this out. I get the error:

```
'Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject''
```

On the line:

```
favourites.append(addNewMemory.text!)
```

```
//MARK:- Core Data
    func save(name: String) {

      guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
      }

      // 1
      let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

      // 2
      let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Memory",
                                   in: managedContext)!

      let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                   insertInto: managedContext)

      // 3
      person.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")

      // 4
      do {
        try managedContext.save()
        favourites.append(person)
      } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    }

    var favourites: [NSManagedObject] = []


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return favourites.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        /*cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "applelogo")
        cell.imageView?.setRounded()
        cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
        */

        let favMemory = favourites[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = favMemory.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String

        return cell
    }
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        insertNewCell()
    }

    func insertNewCell() {

        favourites.append(addNewMemory.text!)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: favourites.count - 1, section: 0)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        addNewMemory.text = ""
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

I expected the app to save the string, but it does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: your object favourites is type of NSManagedObject array and you trying to append string on it so error is appear you have to fetch data from the core data and store it in to the  favourites.

Comment: if you are new to core data tray to learning all concept from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20uHVD2bim0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up the `text` property of the text field and the Core Data entity. Obviously `favourites` is declared as `[NSManagedObject]` so you can't append a string. That's what the error message is telling you.

You have to insert a new record in `insertNewCell`. The easiest solution is to call `save` and return a Bool from `save` to indicate that the insertion was successful.

And you are encouraged to use more contemporary API. If there is no `Memory` subclass create one

```
var favourites = [Memory]()

...

func save(name: String) -> Bool {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate // force unwrapping is perfectly fine

    // 1
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    // 2
    let person = Memory(context: managedContext)

    // 3
    person.name = name

    // 4
    do {
      try managedContext.save()
      favourites.append(person)
      return true
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      return false
    }
}
```

and change `insertNewCell` to

```
func insertNewCell() {
    guard save(name: addNewMemory.text!) else { return }
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: favourites.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    addNewMemory.text = ""
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

`beginUpdates/endUpdates` is pointless.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my problem. Now all of its working. Thank you!

Comment: Quick question though. When I delete a cell, and reload the app, the cell reappears. How could I go about removing a cell and it no longer loading into the tableView.

Comment: Do the opposite way around. Remove the item from `favourites`, delete the item in the context, delete the row and save the context.